# Converting constant voltage to a pulse

Tags: 555, pulse, multivibrator

Im trying to do research for something I can't even name. Basically it goes like this:
[image: converting constant voltage to a short pulse]

It's kind of like a multi-vibrator, but I need it to give a short pulse on the output, while input is a constant voltage. Maybe some of you know some circuits, that would be capable of such task.

Comment: RC + comparator.

Comment: Did the voltage begin at the beginning of time?

Comment: It's just one pulse in the beginning or continued pulses over the time?

Comment: What on the input triggers the single (or multiple) pulses? What is the amplitude of the pulse? Does the amplitude relate to the input amplitude? What is the length of the pulse? Does the length relate to input amplitude or something else?

Comment: Do you want to convert voltage to duration? if so with what factor? i.e. how long should the pulse last if voltage is 10V?

Comment: Yes, voltage began at the start.

No, there is only one pulse over the whole work time of the circuit.

Let's say I have 5V and I want it to last for 3s.

Comment: Perhaps you want a voltage to frequency converter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a one-shot or monostable. Your diagrams should look like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffHlqe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>